# python plot line for each percentile

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, reshape, percentile

How can I plot percentiles computed via `pandas.DataFrame.describe` for each percentile using seaborn?

Currently, I need to iterate over each one. Instead, I want a single chart with all the percentiles. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html 
has some nice examples with hue and style, but I currently wonder how to properly reshape the data frame to be able to use this method.

```
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03'], 'bar':[1,2,3, 4], 'baz':[3,4,5, 6]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
display(df)

df = df.groupby(['dt']).describe()
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index(['dt'], drop=False)
display(df)

import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

# iterate for each column (bar, baz)
df_plot = df[['dt']].copy()

# iterate for each percentile
df_plot['metric'] = df['bar']['25%']
sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='metric', data=df_plot)
plt.show()

df_plot['metric'] = df['bar']['50%']
sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='metric', data=df_plot)
plt.show()

df_plot['metric'] = df['bar']['75%']
sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='metric', data=df_plot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Remove the first 2 `plt.show()`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Wow - ok. This is a lot easier than I thought. Correct. Now I only need to get a legend set up and manually apply the hue/styling. But at least it plots all into a single plot easily.

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='metric', data=df_plot, label='C')` <--- add label to each plot for creating legend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify all of this using the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%pylab inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03'], 'bar':[1,2,3, 4], 'baz':[3,4,5, 6]})
df = df.groupby(['dt']).describe()
sns.lineplot(data=df['baz'][['25%', '50%', '75%']])
```

Result (maybe with an extra `plt.show()`? I don't have pylab installed to test.):

[image]

Comment: This is great! I will still need to fiddle with the styling i.e. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html the fade out displayed from the documentation looks really nice. I also need to figure out how to allow for 2 categories as well i.e. male7female. But most likely, having a separate plot for each category will be best.